# How to use setDefaultNightMode and getConfiguration().uiMode together in one app?

Tags: android, android-night-mode, android-darkmode

I found no solution to this problem. In my MainActivity I use this command to setup the **app dark mode**:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

However I want to see, if the **device dark mode** is activated with this command:

```
int dM = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
```

If the device is in dark mode, uiMode changes its value. The problem is, if setDefaultNightMode is called, it also changes uiMode to the same value. How can I only detect the device dark mode?